# robocopy - do not copy source uncompressed file when zip file of same name present in destination directory

Tags: batch-file, robocopy

I have a batch file which uses robocopy to copy data files from one location to another.  Because of capacity problems on the destination drive, we have created another script which makes zip files of each individual data file and removed the original data file from the system.

How can I modify the batch file so that it only copies new '.dat' files to the destination when there isn't a matching '.zip' file with the same file name? I require the new '.dat' files on the destination drive for processing before conversion to '.zip'

Here's an example of source and destination files:

```
sourceDir\file1.dat
sourceDir\file2.dat
sourceDir\file3.dat
sourceDir\file4.dat
sourceDir\file5.dat
sourceDir\subDir1\file1.dat
sourceDir\subDir1\file2.dat
sourceDir\subDir3\file22.dat

destDir\file2.zip
destDir\file3.zip
destDir\file5.zip
destDir\subDir1\file1.zip
```

Only

```
sourceDir\file1.dat
sourceDir\file4.dat
sourceDir\subDir1\file2.dat
sourceDir\subDir3\file22.dat
```

should be copied into destDir

Thanks!

Erik

The current robocopy script has the following format:

```
robocopy sourceDir destDir *.dat /S /COPY:DA   /XO  /MAXAGE:200
```

Comment: You won't be able to do this with just ROBOCOPY. Look at the `FOR` command (at a command prompt, type `FOR /?`) to process each file individually and determine if it needs copied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop through the files and copy them individually if they don't exist:

```
for %%f in (%sourceDir%\*.dat) do (
    if not exist %destDir%\%%~nf.zip (
        // do something...
    )
)
```